# Laravel: How can I pass my join code to my route so that only users with this code can join a room?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to figure out how to pass a parameter in a route to my controller.

I have an entry **join_code** in my table which is associated to a paper. Every join code is unique and is generated when the user creates a paper.

```
$paper->join_code = $request->uuid;
```

Every paper can have different values, so I want only users with the join code allow to see the view make edits (theoretically every user with the join code can edit it but for now it should be enough for my use case).

I tried it the following way: First I defined the route in my **api.php** file:

```
Route::get('/paper/{join_code}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PaperController@main_paper')->name('show_paper');
```

Now in my **PaperController.php**

```
 public function main_paper($join_code) 
    {
        return view('paper');
    }
```

And in my **paper.blade.php** file:

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="{{route('show_paper' , [request()->get('join_code')])}}">
                <div>
                    <div class="new">
                        Hello
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

So f.e. when a user selects a button join room he can enter the join code and gets redirected to the associated paper which is stored in the blade file. I think the corresponding url for a paper would be: **api/conceptPaper/c5e24dd0-3a1c-11eb-9ad9-8fc9c3260704** . However it is not working and shows a 404.

---

**UPDATE**
The url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/paper/c5e24dd0-3a1c-11eb-9ad9-8fc9c3260704 is throwing a 404. I expected that my blade file is returned.

Error when passing the value in an array as suggested here:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: show_paper] [URI: api/paper/{join_code}]. (View: C:\Users\User\LaravelApp\resources\views\paper.blade.php)
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/paper/c5e24dd0-3a1c-11eb-9ad9-8fc9c3260704

Comment: Can you show the URL that's throwing the 404? Check the browser dev tools' Network tab.

Comment: I updated my answer. Network tab shows nothing. Already checked there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter for the `route()` function should be passed as an associative array.

```
{{ route('show_paper' , ['join_code' => request()->get('join_code')]) }}
```

Comment: Now it says: Missing required parameters . I updated my question.